# Used Tapestry template, reverted, but now not referencing actual index.tml file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty, tapestry

I royally messed up trying to push my changes to my github repository and did something weird in IntelliJ.  It basically automatically reverted me to the original Tapestry framework with their boilerplate Index.tml page.

After some reverting to older versions, I finally got all the files back to their original state.  So, now, if I access my app in the command line then run

```
mvn jetty:run
```

however I keep getting the error below, which does not represent the file its actually accessing (totally different).

How do I get mvn to access the right file, or IntelliJ/Tapestry to get this issue to go away.

:(

Thanks!

William

Comment: Which error? Can you add the error message and stacktrace?

Comment: Maybe I should be a bit more specific.  I reverted, and then made new changes to my index.tml file.  However, when I run maven and visit the localhost it keeps showing the previous version of index.tml.  I have tried clearing mvn cache.  Different browsers.  I have made all the commits to git and sync everything (using intellij).

Comment: Sounds like a git questions to me. Set some breakpoints and debug your app to see what is happening. This won't have anything to do with tapestry, maven or jetty. Could be a number of things: you're running your app from a different directory than where you are editing. You are working on a branch but running an old war. You are not rebuilding your app automatically within your IDE. Anyones guess. Try running the app from the command line vs from the IDE and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found by a nice colleague of mine.  To resolve the issue:

```
mvn clean compile jetty:run
```

This solved all issues.